# How can I use a database and PHP sessions to store a user's shopping cart?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I use a database and PHP sessions to store a user's shopping cart? I am using CodeIgniter, if that helps.

Example code would also be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write an add to basket function like this:

```
function AddToBasket(){
    if(is_numeric($_GET["ID"])){
        $ProductID=(int)$_GET["ID"];
        $_SESSION["Basket"][]=$ProductID;
        $sOut.=ShowBasketDetail();
        return $sOut; 
    }
}
```

In this shopping basket function we save Product IDs in an session array.

Here is what I would have in the show basket function:

```
function ShowBasket(){
    foreach($_SESSION[Basket] as $ProductID){
        $sql="select * from products where ProductID=$ProductID";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
        echo "Product: ".$row[0];
        }
}
```

For each ProudctID in our session basket we make a SQL query to output product information.

Now last but not least, a clear basket function:

```
function ClearBasket(){
    unset($_SESSION[Basket]);
}
```

Don't forget `session_start();` before you add any Product IDs to your session basket. Also don't forget the `mysql_connect();` function, you need this before you make any queries with the database.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you look at [the CodeIgnitor Session Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).

Additionally, you could look at [Chris Shiflett's discussion](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database) on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

how about this ;
- when guest add one item product in the cart

```
  function addCartItem($item_id, $qty)
  {
    $basket = $this->session->userdata('basket');
    if(!$basket)
    {
       $this->session->set_userdata('basket', array($item_id => $qty));
    }
    else
    {
       ## get array from $basket and *merge some new value from input
    }
  }
```