# shopping cart in session how to set values, and remove values? PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, session, shopping-cart

hi all sorry am new in web development
i made a website [my site](http://www.q8movies.com)
but it is almost done but i couldn't find how to make a shopping-cart
i figured out that the best way is by doing it in session
i sow in StackOverFlow a very good example  [see it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316222/how-can-i-use-a-database-and-php-sessions-to-store-a-users-shopping-cart) 
but what to write in a bottom to add the item, if any one has any link to something that may help me please

and when i used the example that i mentioned before when i press on the add-to-cart bottom
this error message present
"Notice: Use of undefined constant Basket - assumed 'Basket' in C:\wamp\www\movies\Action&Adventure_n_c.php on line 35
Notice: Undefined index: Basket in C:\wamp\www\movies\Action&Adventure_n_c.php on line 35

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\movies\Action&Adventure_n_c.php on line 35"

my bottom is

```
<?PHP    
$onpage=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
echo "<a class='art-button' href='$onpage"."?ID=$PID1'>Add to Cart</a>";  
?>
```

please any idea ??

the code for session is this:

```
function AddToBasket(){
   if(is_numeric($_GET["ID"])){
    $ProductID=(int)$_GET["ID"];
    $_SESSION["Basket"][]=$ProductID;
    $sOut.=ShowBasketDetail();
    return $sOut; 
  }
}
```

In this Shoping Basket funktion we save Product IDs in an Session array. Now here the Show Basket funktion:

```
function ShowBasket(){
foreach($_SESSION[Basket] as $ProductID){
    $sql="select * from products where ProductID=$ProductID";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo "Product: ".$row[0];
    }
```

}

Foreach ProudctID in our Session Basket we make a SQL query to output Product Informations...

Now last but not least a clear Basket function:

```
function ClearBasket(){
unset($_SESSION[Basket]);
}
```

---

thanks all for your help really thanks alot, but i found this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZNRvS3FvQo&feature=related) that solve my problem,

best regards to all of you.

---

thanks all for your help really thanks alot, but i found a shoping cart that solve my problem,

```
<?php      
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
        $cart_id=$_GET['id'];
    else
        $cart_id=1;

    if(isset($_GET['action']))
        $action=$_GET['action'];
    else
        $action="none";

    switch($action)
    {
        case "add":
            if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$cart_id]))
                $_SESSION['cart'][$cart_id]++;
            else
                $_SESSION['cart'][$cart_id]=1;
        break;
        case "remove":
            if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$cart_id]))
            {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$cart_id]--;
                if($_SESSION['cart'][$cart_id]==0)
                    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$cart_id]);
            }


        break;
        case "empty":
            unset($_SESSION['cart']);
        break;
    }
        ?>
```

best regards to all of you.

Comment: on click of add to cart link page will refresh and you will get parameter(product_id), to that function.....

Comment: yes, but why this error that i mentioned before ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have meant

```
<?PHP     
$onpage=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
print "<a class='art-button' href='$onpage?ID=$PID1'>Add to Cart</a>";
?>
```

As the above code is not valid PHP

Comment: sorry the <a href > is not in the php i ment by that, that the bottom am using is like that

Comment: OK, but the href='$onpage"."?ID=$PID1' part wouldnt work very well unless in a PHP statement was all.. anyway.  In short, you need to check with your code that you recevied the GET data, just like you would a form, you then need to put the data into your session. eg $_SESSION["cart"]["item1"]=$PID1;

Comment: If you have no basket, then you would get the errors you describe. As the $SESSION["basket"] wont exist. If you check that exists in your show basket routine, that error will go. Does your basket work once you add something?

Comment: i dont know am trying to use it, but i dont know how to add am using the link above, how i can set the basket ?

Comment: Your code above does set the basket.. eg the AddToBasket function, are you calling it?

Comment: no, where i should put the calling to that function? i should set in the link onclick='AddToBasket();'; ??

Answer (score 0):

looks like you didn't start a session. Start the session on the first page, and register the basket class to it. On the next page retrieve the basket object from the session and add the item.

Comment: man i am using the session and the username and password are working fine, but i dont know how to implement the shopping cart soory because my knowledge in PHP is not soo goog :(

Answer (score 0):

Use session array basket variable to store items in the session.
 eg- $_SESSION['basket'][i] = product_id  where i is the index of the array.